# Fastest Way in Python to Parse Space-delimited Numbers

Tags: python, regex

So I am struggling with some code within a loop that will run millions of times. I would like to know which way (in Python) to parse a space-delimited set of fixed-width columns with digits and render them into a shortened form. I will be looping over data like this:

```
entry = "1      0    0    7     1    1    2    3    4    5    6     0"
```

and I essentially need to pull out the 5th, 7th, 8th, 9th, and 10th indicies to transform the numbers into a string identifier.

*Option 1*:
Since the data is fixed width, I could do something like:

```
a,b,c,d,e = entry[28:33],entry[38:43],entry[43:48],entry[48:53],entry[53:59]
```

to pull out the digits (with spaces) and then form my string:

```
return "c"+a.strip()+"x"+b.strip()+"e"+c.strip()+"s"+d.strip()+"n"+e.strip()
```

*Option 2*: Do splits first:

```
fields = entry.split()
return "c"+fields[5]+"x"+fields[7]+"e"+fields[8]+"s"+fields[9]+"n"+fields[10]
```

For a few tests, option 2 runs about 5% faster than option 1. Are there any other options here that could be faster? Maybe a regex with groups? Performance really is paramount here so I am willing to use (with good comments inline) something that isn't high readability.

Comment: You seem to be good at profiling; why not try the regex and see.

Comment: I am currently working on the regex, but I am so bad at regexs. I can't figure out how to capture multiple groups. Perhaps I should deep deeper on figuring that out too.

Comment: `entry.split()`, then use indexes

Comment: I see that in the first option you are assuming that numbers have almost 4 digits, is it the case ?

Comment: You could use Cython for that but I am not sure this will improve significantly the performance.

Comment: Note that fields[5] is the *sixth* index, not the 5th (and so on).

Comment: There is no reason to think a regex would be faster. It has to do more work to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, `entry.split()` will work fine. Here's an example pulling out the 5th, 7th, 8th, 9th, and 10th indices to create a string identifier. Note that the index starts at 0, hence why the numbers are on less.

```
entry = "1      0    0    7     1    1    2    3    4    5    6     0"
elems = entry.split()

string_id = 'c' + str(elems[4]) + 'x' + str(elems[6]) + 'e' + str(elems[7]) + 's' + str(elems[8]) + 'n' + str(elems[9])  # 'c1x2e3s4n5'

print(string_id)  # '12345'
```

Best time out of many runs: `0.00183889195728`

The best time when performing option 1 from your question was: `0.00139979653864`

If you gave multiple entries I could perform better performance tests, but with the limited data, this is the best that can be done for now. If you need more speed than that (these are very small differences in performance), don't use Python. Use C.

Comment: The question isn't *does it works* but *which is faster*

Comment: Numbers doesn't always have only one digit !

Comment: @webNeat it doesn't matter. `entry.split()` will handle it just fine. `"1    110    0  117     1    1    223  3    4    5    6     0".split() = ['1', '110', '0', '117', '1', '1', '223', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0']`

Comment: And in my case, the numbers won't always be one digit.

Comment: @Randy it won't matter. `entry.split()` will work no matter how many digits and no matter how much white space.

Comment: @BobDylan Sorry I didn't see the `split()` call, my bad :P